# Touch command not running in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, exec, child-process

```
let x = execSync(`docker exec ${containerid}  touch output.txt `);
            console.log(x.toString());
```

this code shows a message "docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.
See 'docker exec --help'.

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Execute a command in a running container

but when run it terminal empty output.txt file is created , what is the error.

After consolelog the command which i was running in execSync it looked like /n after container id
This is the ouput i got after printing

```
docker exec 29bd1c231cd34901c730c658ec5b26190845dbf47c996ba024585acf9657e20d
 ls
```

Comment: What is the value of `containerid` here?  In addition to the potential shell-injection attack, I'd expect you wouldn't normally need to use `docker exec` in routine use, and it opens up a number of other security concerns.  Can the main process in the container create this file itself?  What is your actual goal here?

Comment: I am creating an online judge, and for that i wanted to isolate the environment where the user code will run ran this command `docker run -d ubuntu bash -c "tail -f/dev/null"` stored the output of this in containerid , next i wanted to create a file which i will compile in terminal , so something similar to this is in my mind as of now

Comment: previously i done this whole process without docker , and i was getting error because i was accessing the same file , so i used execsync instead of exec

Comment: @DavidMaze I am creating an online judge, and for that i wanted to isolate the environment where the user code will run ran this command docker run -d ubuntu bash -c "tail -f/dev/null" stored the output of this in containerid , next i wanted to create a file which i will compile in terminal , so something similar to this is in my mind as of now.

Comment: Without Docker, how would you create an empty process, then run code inside it?  For what you're describing, the Docker API equivalent of `docker run --rm ...` seems like a better match.

Comment: @DavidMaze Without docker ? I have docker installed , what i did above worked when I tried using terminal, I will try using dockerode .

Comment: It looks the above didnot worked because there was newline char and after trimming it works

Comment: @DavidMaze there is another problem , I am not able to edit the file i created , here is what i did ```docker exec ec407f9d3327 echo thaliva >> input.txt``` , but on running  ```docker exec ec407f9d3327 cat input.txt``` didnot recieved in any ouput , which i interpretated as empty .

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the container id that is returned - the container id has newline character.

So to use the containerid, we first need to trim the newline character, and then it works perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I could not find anything related to it documentation but , after doing console.log it showed a new line character was there so i tried and that luckily worked